# after selecting date from second text on which i have applied jquery date time picker it changes the date in first text box

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

Here are those 2 text boxes both have different ids. when I select end date it changes the value of start date and end date remains empty. I have tried the answer received by the user `user2517610`. it's not working for me. I am not generating elements dynamically.

```
<div class="row"><div class="form-group form-inline col-lg-offset-2  col-sm-ffset-2 col-xs-offset-2"><label style="width: 110px;" >start date</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ctl_survey_startdate_101"></div></div>
<div class="row"><div class="form-group form-inline col-lg-offset-2  col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-offset-2"><label style="width: 110px;">End Date</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ctl_survey_enddate_101"></div></div>
```

this is how I am applying date time picker

```
$('#ctl_survey_startdate_101').datepicker({
    dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd'
});

$('#ctl_survey_enddate_101').datepicker({
    dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd'             
});
```

Comment: are you using any on change events in your script?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Your code is working fine. Check if any events are there in your code. https://jsfiddle.net/8b3atjec/

Comment: $('#ctl_survey_enddate_101').datepicker({
            dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd'             
        })..on("change", function (e) {
  alert("in end date")
});; i have tried this it goes in onchange of startdate but it does not enters in onchange of end date

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen in my entire project it is working fine but when i am opening it in jquery dialog that time only issue occurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('#ctl_survey_startdate_101').datepicker({
    dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd'
});

$('#ctl_survey_enddate_101').datepicker({
    dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd'             
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group form-inline col-lg-offset-2  col-sm-ffset-2 col-xs-offset-2">
    <label style="width: 110px;" >start date</label> 
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ctl_survey_startdate_101">
  </div>
</div>


<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group form-inline col-lg-offset-2  col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-offset-2">
    <label style="width: 110px;">End Date</label> 
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ctl_survey_enddate_101">
  </div>
</div>
```

I have Worked on your code in the snippet and it working fine. 
Your issue might be happening because of some other thing.
Can you please check or if you can add all the code.